# PyQt5 - QFrame size is ignored in window

Tags: python, pyqt5, qframe

I was creating an application with a QFrame on the left side and a control panel on the right. However, I cannot get the QFrame on the left to be sized properly. I created the following example to demonstrate the problem:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFrame, QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, \
    QLabel


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    """Main Windows for this demo."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor."""
        super().__init__()

        self.frame = MyFrame(self)

        layout_main = QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout_left = QVBoxLayout()
        layout_right = QVBoxLayout()

        layout_main.addLayout(layout_left)
        layout_main.addLayout(layout_right)

        self.frame.resize(600, 600)
        layout_left.addWidget(self.frame)

        self.label = QLabel('I am on the right')
        layout_right.addWidget(self.label)

        # self.setGeometry(300, 100, 900, 900)

        self.show()


class MyFrame(QFrame):
    """Custom frame."""

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.setFrameStyle(QFrame.Panel | QFrame.Raised)
        self.setStyleSheet('QFrame { background-color: red; }')


def main():
    """Main function."""

    app = QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I would expect a big red shape on the left but instead I get this:

[image]

Resizing the window (either at runtime by dragging or by setting the geometry in code) does resize the QFrame to neatly fill up half the screen. But I want it to have a predefined fixed size.

Why is `frame.resize` not working as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. Using `frame.setFixedSize()` does exactly what I want:

```
class MyFrame(QFrame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        self.setFixedSize(300, 300)  # < Added this line
```

The frame keeps it size and if I resize the whole window this is respected:

[image]

I am still not sure why `resize()` does nothing.

Comment: `resize` does nothing because the size of the frame in this case is managed by the layout manager that the widget belongs to (i.e. layout_left in this case). The layout manager will automatically adjust the size of the widget depending on the available space and various other factors such as stretching factors, size policy, and minimum and/or maximum size of the widget.